# Overriding Library twice in android studio project manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Min sdkversion of my project is 8.I am using two libraries whose min version is 9 and 10.When I run my project it showed two errors that uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library     Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.brightcove.seamless" to force usage for one.When I did this it asked the same for other library.But since we can use tools:overrideLibrary once I dont know how to overcome this...please help...

Comment: first of all, your app will not work on API 8 devices while you use this libs, so change `minSDK` of your application anв try to launch it one more time)

Comment: try the minSdkVersion 10 and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-Required:

- Add Your library inside gradle with compile scope

In Side AndroidMenifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="xx.tech.cs.xx" >
```

And then above application start tag need to add

```
 <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.brightcove.seamless"/>
```

No need to change the minSDK version of your applications so it will go through with this I hope you can work this code in your program.

I have same issue for the other minSDK=14 version library and my application minSDK is 10 So I use this way.